# pop-up window when button have specific class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create shop in prestashop engine and before I customize product options like add file, choose product size etc. my button is not clickable. I want to add pop-up window with text "Before add product to cart please customize your product." when user click button before customize product.

My button looks like:

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary add-to-cart" data-button-action="add-to-cart" type="submit" disabled="">
   Add to cart
</button>
```

My button have (disabled="") option, but when I customize all necessary actions button do not have this option and I can click" Add to cart" button.

So I think I need make some js script or something in html/CSS to popup window with function "onclick" when button has (disabled="") option.

Best regards,
Rafal

Comment: Please modify the question to include the relevant code that you currently have, and we can help fix your problem.  Also, please read **[ask]** - it will help you ask relevant questions that will get more response. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to add the `disabled` attribute. Instead, you can write some css class for the disabled state of the button, for example using `opacity` and naming it as `disabled-button`. As far as I understood the button will be disabled by default and you can write you button class attribute like `class="btn btn-secondary add-to-cart disabled-button"`. The button is always clickable and all you need to write is a function that toggles `disabled-button` classname and the action accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for reply. The disabled attribute is generate by prestashop/module/template I do not know what. 
But disabled attribute is good for me and I think work fine. I need only to show some pop-up window to my customers due to they do not know why button "Add to cart" is little more transparet.

I did not tell before, before I customize product, button is transparent with opacity attribiute.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that you can't remove the disabled attribute, right?

Comment: No, no, I want to add a pop-up window with text when the user clicks the button before customizing the product. So I think to create a script showing a pop-up window at the click of a button. But the pop-up window will appear when the button has the attribute "disabled", and if the button does not have this attribute, the popup will not be displayed, the button will take you to the next shopping step. I hope I wrote it clearly.

Comment: I think you should target to the container of the button. Because if the button is disabled, there is no way to trigger any of the mouse events. If you are using jQuery you can do this ```$('.add-to-cart').parent().click(/*function: if not customized show popup*/)```. Not the best option for selecting the parent element but I hope you got the idea.